# Объединение массивов через один

Tags: php

объединяю два массива с помощью array_merge, но мне нужно чтобы через каждый 1 элемент массив №1 был вставлен элемент массива №2. Как такое реализовать? То есть поочередно

Comment: цикл............просто цикл....

Answer (score 0):

Если массивы одинаковой длины, то можно так:

```
<?php
 
$a = [1, 3, 5];
$b = [2, 4, 6];
$c = [];
 
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $c[] = $v;
    $c[] = $b[$k];
}
 
var_dump($c);
/*
 array (size=6)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
  5 => int 6
*/
```